# WPF Rectangle Label Blurry

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the code below to draw text over a rectangle in a WPF canvas but it seems to stretch/squash the text and sometimes the back colour does not fill the entire box.

I'm looking for a way to make sure the box is always filled and the text is clear. Probably some form of dynamic font sizing?

Thanks.

[image]

```
Rectangle elip = new Rectangle();
elip.Height = 6;
elip.Width = 6;   

Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(n.Value.R,
                            n.Value.G, n.Value.B));

Label TB = new Label();
TB.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
TB.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
TB.Background = brush;
TB.FontSize = 12;
TB.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
TB.Content = n.Value.Stations[0].TrackId;

BitmapCacheBrush bcb = new BitmapCacheBrush(TB);
elip.Fill = bcb;
elip.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
elip.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
elip.MouseDown += ElipOnMouseDown;
Canvas.SetTop(elip, n.Value.Y - elip.Width / 2);
Canvas.SetLeft(elip, n.Value.X - elip.Height / 2);
cMain.Children.Add(elip);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stretch the text using a viewbox.

I recommend using a usercontrol to encapsulate all your markup for things like this. You would have to have many thousands of these things before the overhead of a usercontrol vs building rectangles and whatnot would be significant.

I built this usercontrol:

```
         Height="18" Width="24">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="Magenta"
                >
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="2"
                       />
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Might not be precisely what you want in terms of width, height or whatever.

You could instantiate one of these, set it's Tag, canvas top and left and add it to the canvas.

Here's the equivalent markup I used to prove it:

```
    Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <local:StationView Canvas.Left="20"
                               Canvas.Top="100"
                               Tag="16B"/>
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```